# why i can not access new product List from MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi! i try to learn Asp.net MVC.i created a sample application to learn it. But press f5 return server error. Where do l make a mistake? where is the problem? there is a navigator bar Home/About/Product . if i press Product, error return to me.

[image]
**Cotroller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models.Db;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Products/

        public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyDbEntities())
            {
                ViewData["Products"] = ctx.Products;
                return View();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.Db.Product>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication1.Models.Db" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication1.Controllers" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    ProductDetail
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>ProductDetail</h2>
    <ul>

<% foreach (var m in (IEnumerable<Products>)ViewData["Products"])
     { %>

     <li><%= m.ProductName %></li>

<% } %>
</ul>

</asp:Content>
```

**site.Master:**

```
            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                     <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", "Product")%></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", "Product")%>
```

the action name ProductDetail is not in your controller you have GetAll action name

u need

```
 public ActionResult ProductDetail()
    {
        using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            return View(db.Products.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide more information such as the actual server error?

Quickly looking at the code the View name is wrong.
going to /Products/ expects a view named Products not product details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the Controller name and the View folder name. Also between the Action name and the View name.

**Products**Controller -> **Product** Folder in Views

**GetAll** Action -> **ProductDetail.aspx** View

Rename to:

**Product**Controller -> Product Folder in Views

**ProductDetail** Action -> ProductDetail.aspx View

Also, make this line:

```
ViewData["Products"] = ctx.Products;
```

like this:

```
ViewData["Products"] = ctx.Products.ToList();
```

Your views shouldn't be making calls to the database.

Comment: i do it what you say. But result is the same:    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Test", "Detail", "Product")%></li>

Comment: @Penguen it should be:
<li><%: Html.ActionLink("Test", "ProductDetail", "Product")%></li>

Can you post the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you doing the default routing.

1. The Problem is that your controller is named `ProductsController` (pluralized). Change the name to `ProductController` or the name of the viewfolder to `Products`.
2. Another problem is that your Controller does not contain a ActionMethod `ProductDetail`, 
   your link in the `site.Master` pointing to `ProductController.ProductDetail`

If you want to learn Asp.NET Mvc i encourage you to check out the following tutorials.

- [NerdDinner Tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)
- [MVC/Tutorials/Chapter 3. MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)
- [Asp.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

**hope this helps**

Comment: i do it what you say. But result is the same:    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Test", "Detail", "Product")%></li>

Comment: Yes because you have no Detail ActionMethod. At the moment your Controller only have a method called "GetAll".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to be more specific. What error do you get?

Now, I think I see what the problem is, but I'm just guessing because you didn't post the error. For what I see, you pass to the view the IQueryable: `ctx.Products` without enumerating it.

Then the view tries to enumerate it, but the context is disposed, so the query cannot run. I guess the error you're getting is something like "the context is not available" or something like this.

First of all, try to change the statement like this: `ctx.Products.ToList()` and see if the error goes away.

Another thing I spotted you're using the dictionary, while using a strongly typed ViewModel would be much better (or at least use dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

if you do not specify a View name, the application will look for a view with the name of your method. I.e:

```
public ActionResult GetAll()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDbEntities())
        {
            ViewData["Products"] = ctx.Products;
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Is looking for a view "Product/GetAll.aspx". Solutions:

- change the name of the method
- change the name of the view
- Specify the view name by doing `return View("ProductDetail");`